# Why use dynamic SQL in Oracle? I don't understand the difference between the two ways of writing

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

```
sql_1 := 'select count(1)
                 from table_1 a
                 where a.col_id = '''|| v_1 ||''' 
                 and a.col2 like ''%'|| v_2 ||'';
execute immediate sql_1
        into v_new;
-----------------------------------------------      
select count(1)
        into v_new
from table_1 a
where a.col_id = '''|| v_1 ||''' 
and a.col2 like ''%'|| v_2 ||'';
```

I think the effect of the two methods is the same in a procedure. Why is the first one better?

Comment: Dynamic SQL is necessary when parts of query that are fixed need to be dynamic, namely column names, table names, schema or other database objects.

Comment: In your case the first block of code is PL/SQL (programming language SQL) and second just an SQL query, and have different uses.

Comment: You are implemeting SQL Injection... on purpose? Those examples can be implemented without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is the first one better please

Dynamic SQL is not better as, among other reasons, the syntax errors, etc. will be raised at run-time and not compile time so you cannot debug issues as easily.

If you do not need dynamic SQL then do not use it:

```sql
select count(1)
into   v_new
from   table_1 a
where  a.col_id = v_1 
and    a.col2  like '%'|| v_2
```

If you must use dynamic SQL (don't) then use bind variables (to prevent the SQL engine from having to re-parse the statement when you change a variable and to avoid SQL injection issues):

```sql
sql_1 := 'select count(1)
          from   table_1 a
          where  a.col_id = :1
          and    a.col2 like ''%'' || :2';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_1 INTO v_new USING v_1, v_2;
```

However, you should reserve dynamic SQL for when you must dynamically specify identifiers (rather than values) and, even then, it should be a prompt to step back and review what you are doing and whether you can change your approach to avoid using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, dynamic SQL is generally used in case you have several tables with more or less similar structures on which you perform similar data processing and you do not wish to write similar code for the N similar tables. Then you may use dynamic SQL with execute immediate or the facilities of dbms_sql.
The main problem when using dynamic SQL is that it needs instrumentation so that you may debug the runtime errors which occur much more frequently than in non-dynamic SQL which is compiled. Dynamic SQL cannot possibly be compiled on stored program, unit or PL/SQL block compilation and is parsed at runtime, which quite often leads to errors because of wrongly compose SQL statements.
Thus, it's best to avoid as much as possible writing dynamic SQL. Use dynamic SQL only to avoid writing something la 10x, 20x, 100x times more lines of code because you have 10, 20, 100 tables with similar structures which require similar data processing.
Sometimes you may avoid using dynamic SQL by designing the database tables differently. Thus, instead of having 100 tables with similar structures, you may have only one table which has an extra column - say code_case - for those 100 cases, eventually partitioned by that column.